Notifications in Kotlin are never shown
Notifications in Kotlin are never shown, in the app settings I see that they are active but they are never notified by the app, I tested the same functionality in Java and in that case they work (modified to adapt them to the Kotlin language)
This is my classes
internal class NewNotificationHelper(private val mContext: Context) {

    var sqliteHelper: SqliteHelper = SqliteHelper(mContext)

    init {

        if (SharedPreferencesManager.notificationTone == null)
            SharedPreferencesManager.notificationTone =
                RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, getSound()).toString()
    }

    fun createNotification() {


        d("createNotification", "" + SharedPreferencesManager.reminderOpt)
        d("createNotification V", "" + SharedPreferencesManager.reminderVibrate)
        if (SharedPreferencesManager.reminderOpt === 1) return
        if (reachedDailyGoal() && !SharedPreferencesManager.notificationStatus) return
        val intent = Intent(mContext, NewDrinkActivity::class.java)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

        val intFlags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        } else {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        }

        val resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, intFlags)


        val snoozeIntent = Intent(mContext, SelectSnoozeFragment::class.java)
        snoozeIntent.setAction("SNOOZE_ACTION")
        snoozeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        val snoozePendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, snoozeIntent, intFlags)
        val addWaterIntent = Intent(mContext, SelectBottleFragment::class.java)
        addWaterIntent.setAction("ADD_WATER_ACTION")
        addWaterIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        val addWaterPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            mContext,
            0,
            addWaterIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )


        val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        mBuilder.setLargeIcon(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                mContext.resources,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            )
        )
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(mContext.resources.getString(R.string.drink_water))
            .setContentText("" + get_today_report())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary))

        if (SharedPreferencesManager.reminderOpt === 0 && !SharedPreferencesManager.reminderVibrate) {
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mBuilder.setSound(getSound())
            }
        } else if (SharedPreferencesManager.reminderOpt === 0 && SharedPreferencesManager.reminderVibrate) {
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mBuilder.setSound(getSound())
            }
        } else if (SharedPreferencesManager.reminderOpt === 2 && !SharedPreferencesManager.reminderVibrate) {
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mBuilder.setSound(null)
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mBuilder.setSound(null)
            }
        }
        mBuilder.addAction(
            R.drawable.ic_plus,
            mContext.resources.getString(R.string.add_water),
            addWaterPendingIntent
        )
        mBuilder.addAction(
            R.drawable.ic_notification,
            mContext.resources.getString(R.string.snooze),
            snoozePendingIntent
        )

        val mNotificationManager =
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mNotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            mNotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_VIBRATE_CHANNEL_ID)
            if (SharedPreferencesManager.reminderOpt === 0) {
                if (!SharedPreferencesManager.reminderVibrate) {
                    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                    val notificationChannel =
                        NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Reminder", importance)
                    notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
                    notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
                    notificationChannel.setSound(null, null)
                    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
                    notificationChannel.vibrationPattern =
                        longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
                    assert(mNotificationManager != null)
                    mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)

                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                        notificationChannel
                    )
                } else {
                    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                        NOTIFICATION_VIBRATE_CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Vibrate Reminder",
                        importance
                    )
                    notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
                    notificationChannel.setSound(null, null)
                    notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
                    notificationChannel.enableVibration(false)
                    notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0)
                    assert(mNotificationManager != null)
                    mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_VIBRATE_CHANNEL_ID)
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
                }
            } else {
                if (!SharedPreferencesManager.reminderVibrate) {
                    val channel_none = NotificationChannel(
                        NOTIFICATION_SILENT_CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Silent Reminder",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                    )
                    channel_none.setSound(null, null)
                    channel_none.enableVibration(true)
                    channel_none.vibrationPattern =
                        longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
                    assert(mNotificationManager != null)
                    mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_SILENT_CHANNEL_ID)
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel_none)
                } else {
                    val channel_none = NotificationChannel(
                        NOTIFICATION_SILENT_VIBRATE_CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Silent-Vibrate Reminder",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                    )
                    channel_none.setSound(null, null)
                    channel_none.enableVibration(false)
                    channel_none.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0)
                    assert(mNotificationManager != null)
                    mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_SILENT_VIBRATE_CHANNEL_ID)
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel_none)
                }
            }
        }
        assert(mNotificationManager != null)
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build())
    }

    

    companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_SILENT_CHANNEL_ID = "10002"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_VIBRATE_CHANNEL_ID = "10003"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_SILENT_VIBRATE_CHANNEL_ID = "10004"
    }
}

This is Receiver
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        d(DEBUG_TAG, "Recurring alarm; requesting download service.")
        acquire(context)
        release()


        val action = "" + intent.action
        if (action.equals("SNOOZE_ACTION", ignoreCase = true)) {

            val snoozeIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            val snoozePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, snoozeIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            val alarms = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            alarms.setExact(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).timeInMillis + 2 * 60000,
                snoozePendingIntent
            )
            val notificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.cancel(0)
        } else if (action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {

            val alarmHelper = NewAlarmHelper(context)
            alarmHelper.createAlarm()
        } else {

            val notificationHelper = NewNotificationHelper(context)
            notificationHelper.createNotification()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val DEBUG_TAG = "AlarmReceiver"
    }
}

Finally Manifest
 <receiver
            android:name=".utils.receiver.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="com.test.intent.action.ALARM" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

As explained before, with the code written in Java the notifications were displayed correctly, but now they are not

Does the AlarmReceiver receive the intent and createNotification() method is being called?

in method onReceive on AlarmReceiver class I call createNotification()

Yeah, I can see that in the code but can you confirm if the createNotification() is being invoked? Maybe just print a message in Log to verify

I put the logs in the OnReceive method and no logs are ever called

It means AlarmReceiver is not listening for broadcasts.

Apps that target the API level 26 or higher can't register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest unless the broadcast is sent specifically to them. Read more here
That's why your AlarmReceiver is not receiving any broadcast for com.test.intent.action.ALARM.
I found this article helpful in implementing the Alarm Broadcast
Link: https://medium.com/@benexus/background-services-in-android-o-862121d96c95
